# MAGIT: "precomposed unicode is not supported"

Tags: magit, character-encoding

I am trying to commit in my Emacs folde, and I get this message below:

```
"precomposed unicode is not supported".
```

I have run on my Terminal "git config core.precomposeunicode false" but the problem persists after restarting Emacs. Anybody with the same problem and a solution? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try setting the value globally: `git config --global core.precomposeunicode false`.

Comment: It worked, thanks very much.

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this setting to take effect in all repositories, then you have to use the `--global` (or `--system`) argument:

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode false
```